nextjs - Dynamic import re-render multiple time
I'm fairly new to dynamic import, but I'm struggling to make it works properly.
If I dynamically import a component in a component where I update state, the first one will be reimported again (displaying the 'loading' state, or just blink).
What am I missing here ?
I made a simple demo here
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/lm3pxr
The red banner keep being imported everytime I update the counter, is that normal ? Even with memo, it keep rendering everytime.
Thanks a lot for the help.
